# Neo4j Bold connection timed out

Tags: neo4j, debian, port

I just installed neo4j on my dedicated server. I openned 7474 and 7687 port on firewall. I can access to the browser of neo4j, but when I try to `:connect server` is results in a `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` javascript error...

neo4j version : 3.2.3

`dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0` is uncommented

```
# Bolt connector
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:7687

# HTTP Connector. There must be exactly one HTTP connector.
dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
dbms.connector.http.listen_address=:7474

# HTTPS Connector. There can be zero or one HTTPS connectors.
dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
dbms.connector.https.listen_address=:7473
```

Where did i make a mistake ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm facing same issue!